# php find exact match and delete

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть код который ищет число в файле, и удаляет его если оно присутствует, а если нет то ничего не делает:

```
$key = $_REQUEST['del'];
$filename = 'list.txt';
$lines = file($filename);
$output = '';

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!strstr($line, $key)) {
        $output .= $line;
    } 
}
file_put_contents($filename, $output);
```

Но проблемы возникают когда допустим в файле число 11 или 15 и при попытке удалить число 1, которого там нет, удалятся и 11 и 15 (то есть все что начинается с 1).
Как сделать так чтобы удалялось только точное число? Пытался поменять strstr на preg_match, не получилось...

Comment: Да уже догадался, просто большинство вопросов на английском мне всегда попадались, вот и подумал что тут только на английском общение

Comment: Тут просто несколько разных форумов

Comment: Уже перевел, спасибо

Comment: вам файл по строкам то зачем вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то вроде - `(?:\D|^)(1)(?:\D|$)` (то что в первое в голову пришло), найти 1 если вокруг не цифры.

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71c9ac09b1069a9f2c69a578d3116c8e53a5b0dd)

```
$key = 1;
$lines = ['asda asdf sdfasdas 11 adsdsdf', 'фыавыва ывавва  1 ыпвап ываыв 1'];

$output = '';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!preg_match("/(?:\D|^)($key)(?:\D|$)/", $line)) {
        $output .= $line;
    } 
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: if (!preg_match("/(?:\D|^)$line(?:\D|$)/", $key)) - не сработало

Comment: вы перепутали переменные местами

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Читайте файл целиком, зачем он вам по строкам?

```
$txt = file_get_contents("list.txt"); 
$value = 15; // число для удаления
$txt = preg_replace("/\b($value)\b/", "", $txt);
file_put_contents("list.txt", $txt)
```

Впрочем, нет смысла записывать контент файла обратно, если совпадение не найдено. Поэтому можете:

1. либо предварительно проверить совпадения, и если они имеются провести замену и сохранить в файл.
2. Либо второй вариант - провести замену, и проверить длину строк до замены и после, если не совпадает - то записать.

не забывайте также, что входные данные необходимо провалидировать, прежде чем подставить в регулярное выражение. То есть если вы хотите убрать число, то удостоверьтесь, что передается именно число. В прочих случаях экранируйте значения с помощью `preg_escape`.